# How to stop Android Service started with a custom intent

Tags: android, android-studio, android-intent, service

I built a class called MService extend Service in Android Studio , I started the service like this: - inside onClick associated with a button-

```
Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MService.class);
serviceIntent.putExtra("ID", "1"); 
startService(serviceIntent);
```

The Service `onStartCommand` method lunched and worked pretty good..

The problem is I don't know how to end the Service when a Button clicked, I tried to do this:

```
stopService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MService.class));
```

inside a onClick method , the  `onDestroy` lunched, but the Service still running
How can I stop it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> inside a onClick method , the  onDestroy lunched, but the Service still running

If `onDestroy()` of your service was called, then afterwards, the service is not running. *Your code* might still be running.

If you start things in a service, such as a background thread, it is *your job* to stop them and clean that up, typically in your `onDestroy()` method.

Comment: can I ask a silly question? if I have multiple users use the app by different usernames and I have one Service class.. if one of them stopped the service, it will not stop the service for the other users. am I right? I'm new in this field, thanks

Comment: @lolowa: If by "multiple users", you mean multiple accounts on the Android device... I have not played with that in the context of services, and so I am not completely certain what the behavior would be. If by "multiple users" you mean that your app has its own concept of users and letting the app switch between them... from the OS's standpoint, that does not matter. Services are natural singletons, so there will only ever be one service instance for your app.